# Token definitions on Substrate

Tags: substrate

When I learn about Polkadot Substrate, I come up with a few questions:

1. Are all the tokens in Parachain called `unit`, and can we set a name to distinguish them?
2. How does the token in Parachain be set? (for example, where does this `Erc20Config` in `chain_spec.rs` of [erc-20 example](https://github.com/parity-samples/substrate-erc20/blob/master/src/chain_spec.rs) come from?)
3. In the above `chain_spec.rs` example, I suppose it is a user-generated `Balance` **besides** Parachain native tokens, is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very good explanation of the token definitions from Substrate Community, I just forward it here:

- `Unit`: smallest denomination of "value" in substrate (like "wei" for
  eth)
- `Balance`: is a module that comes out of the box for you. You can
  think of this as Substrate's "native" notion of the accounts model.
  Take a look at: https://crates.parity.io/srml_balances/index.html
- `erc20`: is a just new example that builds on top of Balances &
  demonstrates you can build easily build ERC tokens using Substrate.
  this is non-"native", in your terms.